# Handling parent view touches

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have UIView which have 3 subviews and I need to handle touches everywere on superview and on subviews also, but subviews intercepts touches. How can I do this?
Thanks.
UPD: So more simple method does not exist? It turns out easier to catch an event apart then inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You could disable the subviews from accepting touches using

```
[subView setUserinteractionEnabled: NO];
```

This way they will not intercept touch events, and they will be sent to the parent view only.

If you want both the views to receive the events, you could catch the event in the subviews and then send them manually to the parent view.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea. +1

Comment: Would be cool to hear some guidance on how best to catch the event in the subviews and then send them manually to the parent view. :]

Answer (score 2):

You need to override touch events in subviews as below:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; 
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved: touches withEvent:event]; 
    [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I think each call needs to only call super and *not* sefl.nextResponder.  See docs for `-(void)touches*:withEvent:`